# Python match raw HTTP POST data

Tags: python, regex

I have the following examples of raw HTTP data, any idea how can I match the posted data? Like `"id=2134&var=test&anothervar=983344"` (this is just an example, variables are different in names that's why they are `variables`)

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 39
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id=2134&var=test&anothervar=983344
```

Tried many regex matches with no good result because I can't rely on any permanent match in the data besides `=`, `&` and maybe `POST` and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
If it helps, the POST data is always ended with `\r\n` so can be matched as end of data.

even "more" raw:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: curl/7.27.0\r\n
Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Content-Length: 39\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
\r\n
id=2134&var=test&anothervar=983344&yetanothervar=u43333A\r\n
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do? Why do you want to match it?

Comment: A small personal project, Apache log parser and so on...

Comment: Yes but, by _matching_ it? What do you want to do with it exactly? Store them at a dictionary for example? Do you want to match the whole request or only the POST data?

Comment: Only the POST data, no headers, not cookies or content length/type ...

Comment: Ok I'm not sure what you're asking so I'll post it here. This is a way to parse a query string into a dict: `import urlparse;urlparse.parse_qs('id=2134&var=test&anothervar=983344')`. That will return a dict object.

Comment: I know how to use urlparse, as I asked is I don't know how to match only the POST data from the raw request, like `id=2134&var=test&anothervar=983344` or `something=aaaa&var=88382&anothervar=bb44b&yetanothervar=somethingelse`, the way to parse it is not hard.

Comment: Ok sorry, let's see if someone else can help.

Comment: Need some regex like "[a-z]=[a-zA-Z0-9]&[a-z]=[a-zA-Z0-9]*" to match the POST data above.

Comment: The HTTP standard says that anything after the first two consecutive new lines is data, not headers. Perhaps look for that?

Comment: Yes. How can I match all data between two consecutive new lines (`\r\n`) until next new line (`\r\n`)?

Comment: How does `re.findall(r'^.*\r\n\r\n(.*)', data)` do?

Comment: Yes, something like this, anyway I need to match the printable characters between 2 new lines and other new line like this `'^.*\r\n\r\n([a-zA-Z0-9&=])\r\n'` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I've posted my regex as an answer -it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the HTTP standard, then anything after the first two consecutive new lines is post data. This regex will match that:

```
re.findall(r'^.*\r\n\r\n(.*)', data, re.MULTILINE)
```

If, as you said in the comments, you want to match up to and not including the last `\r\n`, then tack that on the end:

```
re.findall(r'^.*\r\n\r\n(.*)\r\n', data, re.MULTILINE)
```

Or, if you only want to match those characters:

```
re.findall(r'^.*\r\n\r\n([A-Za-z0-9&=]*)\r\n', data, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for the answer! And thanks for the long time bearing with me :)